# Show ampersand in Markdown syntax highlighting in Compodoc

Tags: markdown, compodoc

I am trying to do an SCSS code block in Markdown but cannot get the ampersand to show up.

```
.my-class {
  &:before{
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
}
```

Here is what I have tried so far along with results:

`&amp;` shows the text.

`&#38;` shows the literal of what I just typed.

`&` just shows a space.

Comment: what do you mean, ampersands don't show up in markdown? It did show up here.

Comment: Please provide the rendered HTML and perhaps also the HTML you expected. You may need to use your browsers "view source" feature to access the HTML.

Comment: yes, it shows up here.  I am doing it in markdown using compodoc.  I can't figure out a way to just show you what my markdown looks like because it ends up formatted here.  If I don't mark it as code block then stack overflow will not let me post it.  basically I am wrapping what is above with ```css.  I expect to see & but instead I see a space if I do &, and the literal string for the other two.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter **a zero-width space** after the ampersand:

```
.my-class {
  &<zero-width space>:before{
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
}
```

You can copy a zero-width space from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space#Usage).